# How to split into train, test and CV in an non-reshuffle order

Tags: python

I know the question may have been asked before but I am afraid I can't find the answer.

How may I split dataset into training (70%), test (15%) and cross validation (15%) sets in an non-reshuffle order (chronological order) in Python?

So far, I have tired

```
 `dx = pd.read_csv('eq_fut_test.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0], 
 skiprows=0, header=0)                                                     
 dx = dx.fillna(method='pad')    
 X_train, X_validate, X_test = np.split(dx.sample(frac=1), [int(.7*len(dx)), 
 int(.8*len(dx))]) `
```

However, the dataset are split randomly.

Any light shed on this is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

[Data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gp422p88ygb4n0u/ccy_test.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Your question is broad. Can you show us what you've tried so far and where precisely you got stuck? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52138064/edit) to do this. Also see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You want sklearn train_test_split function [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test_cross = train_test_split(dx.sample(frac=1), test_size=0.30, shuffle=False)
X_test, X_cross, = train_test_split(X_test_cross, test_size=0.5, shuffle=False)
```

The `0.5` in the 3rd line is because you have 30% of the data and 50% of 30% gives you 15% each.

Comment: Many thanks Ksooklall. But the data are not split in chronological order. How may I do it please?

Comment: shuffle=False will not change the order of your data. Make sure it's in chronological order before splitting.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. But using the codes  you provided and ensuring the order is chronological before splitting, I end up having different orders every time. Please kindly advise how I may fix it. Thanks

Comment: remember you are shuffling the data with dx.sample(frac=1). You should convert the section of the df to a np.array then then pass it in.

Comment: I must be being very stubborn, dx = dx.values get rid of the headers and I cannot even split the data. How may I convert from df to np.array without losing its headers?

Comment: you could just pass in your `df` as in `train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)`

Comment: sorry Ksooklall. I am afraid I don't quite get what you mean. Please could you kindly paste the codes that I should do. Many thanks